# How do I add a web part page in SharePoint 2013 when 'Site Pages' is missing?

Tags: 2013, library, web-part-page

This is a pretty straightforward question: How do I add a web part page in SharePoint 2013?

There is, however, a minor twist. The site I'm adding it to is from a custom template that **doesn't contain the Site Pages list** and wiki libraries I create myself don't offer the option to create a web part page.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I have a sitepages library but still cannot add a webpart page. I go to New Document and only wiki page is available, no webpart page. The WIKI homepage feature is not activated on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't they in the masterpage gallery? Can you just copy one from there and insert into your library of choice?

EDIT: Only relevant if you're talking code, just seen you're talking 2013, and thus the web interface. In which case there's a Wiki Site Feature to let you create wiki and WP Pages I think.

Comment: As we discussed on Twitter: https://twitter.com/StuartPegg/status/357074108556656640 turning on and off the the "Wiki Page Home Page" feature you mention creates the Site Pages list, working around this issue.

Comment: As a side-note for future readers; it seems the easiest way to create the Site Pages library is to enable the Publishing feature, which is not available on Foundation edition.

Comment: Another easy way to create the Site Pages library: If you have SharePoint Designer, open your site with it. Site Pages will be displayed in the Navigation under Site Objects, even if it does not exist. Click on the Site Pages node, and the library will be created in the Background for you. The same applies for the Site Assets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new content type to the document library (site pages library if that is the one you want to add web part pages to).  Add the Web Part Page content type.  It is in the Document group.  Then you will have in the New button on the document library the option for a Web Part Page

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just go to Site Settings > Site Features and active SharePoint Server Publishing? That should give you the Pages library and allow you to use a web part page layout.

Comment: I imagine that needs the Publishing feature. See my last comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the below URL directly to create a "WebPart Page",

```
SiteURL/_layouts/15/spcf.aspx?List=%7BSitePages Library ID Here%7D
```

Note: To get the SitePages Library ID, go to Site Pages Library settings and in the URL, copy everything after `List=`